# AngularJS Binding During Routing Declaration

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('Desktop',
        {
            url: '/Desktop',
            templateUrl: '/Views/{{param}}/Desktop/MainDesktopView.html'
        });
```

So that `param` is a variable and can be changed on reloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateUrl` can be a function, so I guess you can try this to construct a path to the template dynamically based on the value of `param`:

```
$stateProvider.state('Desktop', {
    url: '/Desktop',
    templateUrl: function() {
        return '/Views/' + param + '/Desktop/MainDesktopView.html';
    }
});
```

I'm not sure where `param` comes from, but if it is a route parameter you can then use an argument passed to `templateUrl` function:

> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following parameters:
>
> {array.} - state parameters extracted from the current $location.path() by applying the current state